# Strip first 2 characters and replace with another

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This seems like quite a silly basic question but it seems something I have completely passed over in my knowledge.

Basically I have a string representing a phone number (0 being the area code): **0828889988**

And would like to replace the first zero with a 27 (South African dialing code) as I am pretty sure it will always be so, my SMS api requires it in international format but I want the user to enter it in local format, so should be: **27828889988**

Is there a line or two of code I can call to replace that first character with the two others?

As is - I can think around a workaround solution but as I am not sure of the direct syntax will be quite a few lines long.

Comment: value = "27" + value.Substring(2) or maybe 1 (my VB tells me it should be 2, but vb.net might be different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim number as String = "0828889988"
number = "27" + number.SubString(1)

return number //returns "27828889988"
```

Comment: Wonderful. Similar to the Java Syntax I used to know! Thanks.